# Pitivi Crashes Ubuntu after minimising the window

Tags: crash, pitivi

When I try to minimise Pitivi using the minimise button:

[image: Screenshot of Pitivi with button highlighted]

It crashes all of Ubuntu. By this, I mean the monitor stops receiving an input, then the computer makes the restart noise and it goes onto the log-in screen. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Pitivi 0.94 (64 bit), and I have 8 GB of RAM (I don't know if that's relevant)

Answer (score 3):

[This is a known bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=741272). I reported it but they don't seem to be fixing it. They blame it on compiz. It might help if you also comment on the bug or file the bug for compiz in Ubuntu 14.04.

I have experienced many bugs in Pitivi. It looks nice on first sight, but OpenShot is a lot more stable...

Comment: Same here. Pitivi is not safe if you don't want to lose hours of work.

Answer (score 0):

My tests with v.0.93 (currently available through the software center) do not exhibit this problem under 14.04 32-bit. I suggest downgrading to that version until such time as the problem with v.0.94 is resolved. I also found Openshot and kdenlive to be more reliable. Since I am unable to reproduce the problems that you are having, you should double-check that you have all the dependencies installed. Issue the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio 
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer1.0-0
```

Thumbnails exist and playback works as expected.

Sources:

Experience

http://wiki.pitivi.org/wiki/Dependencies

Comment: It might be through my own incompetence, but that version has issues too (there are no thumbnails on images and  the playback plays nothing)

Comment: @Orfby same here.. Although it happens less regular on v.0.93